# How to use inline C# in the browser instead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor

I have just discovered Microsoft introduced Blazor which allows C# code to be run in the browser. When I looked at some tutorials it seems like you need asp.net core backend server for this to work. It'd be nice if I could type C# code in the browser like:

```
<script>

    //C# code
    string myName = "John";
    alert(myName);

</script>
```

instead of

```
<script>

    //Javascript code
    var myName = "John";
    alert(myName);

</script>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: With .NET Core 3.1 you can utilise Blazor to build UI with C# (instead of JS for example). Check out the docs if you haven't already for examples and syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't just put the C# code in a `script` tag. Browsers don't know how to parse and run C# code. What Blazor does is compile C# (on the server) into .Net assemblies, which are then run in the browser via [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/). Details in the [Blazor introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Here's an excerpt that seems relevant:

> Blazor apps are based on components. A component in Blazor is an element of UI, such as a page, dialog, or data entry form.
>
> ...
>
> The component class is usually written in the form of a Razor markup page with a `.razor` file extension. Components in Blazor are formally referred to as Razor components. Razor is a syntax for combining HTML markup with C# code designed for developer productivity. Razor allows you to switch between HTML markup and C# in the same file with IntelliSense support. Razor Pages and MVC also use Razor. Unlike Razor Pages and MVC, which are built around a request/response model, components are used specifically for client-side UI logic and composition.
>
> The following Razor markup demonstrates a component (`Dialog.razor`), which can be nested within another component:
>
> ```
> <div>
>     <h1>@Title</h1>
>
>     @ChildContent
>
>     <button @onclick="OnYes">Yes!</button>
> </div>
>
> @code {
>     [Parameter]
>     public string Title { get; set; }
>
>     [Parameter]
>     public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
>
>     private void OnYes()
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("Write to the console in C#! 'Yes' button was selected.");
>     }
> }
> ```

And:

> When a Blazor WebAssembly app is built and run in a browser:
>
> - C# code files and Razor files are compiled into .NET assemblies.
> - The assemblies and the .NET runtime are downloaded to the browser.
> - Blazor WebAssembly bootstraps the .NET runtime and configures the runtime to load the assemblies for the app. The Blazor WebAssembly runtime uses JavaScript interop to handle DOM manipulation and browser API calls.